# post request not working in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When I search in the browser as localhost:/users/register

I am getting `Cannot GET /users/register` but I have specified the request as post in router. I have imported the body-parser in the app.js

The post request is present in routes/users.js

```js
router.post("/register",(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("Post request");
    let newUser=new User({
        name:req.body.name,
        email:req.body.email,
        username:req.body.username,
        password:req.body.password
    })
    User.addUser(newUser,(err,user)=>{
        if(err)
            res.json({success:false,msg:"Failed to register user"})
        else
            res.json({success:true,msg:"User registration successful"})
    })
})
```

Schema in models/user.js

```js
const mongoose=require("mongoose")
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs")
const config = require("../config/database")

const UserSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    name:{type:String},
    email:{type:String,required:true},
    username:{type:String,required:true},
    password:{type:String,required:true}
})

const User = module.exports=mongoose.model("User",UserSchema)


module.exports.getUserById=function(id,callback){
    User.findById(id,callback)
}

module.exports.getUserbyUsername=function(username,callback){
    query={username:username}
    User.findOne(query,callback)
}

module.exports.addUser=function(newUser,callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10,(err,salt)=>{
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password,salt,(err,hash)=>{
            newUser.password=hash
            newUser.save(callback)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: try calling this via postman in chrome or rest-client in firefox, else, the direct calls will always be treated as GET

Answer (score 0):

1. your route is /register not /users/register
2. you have to pass the parameters since your using post
3. Use Postman and verify the request as below example

[image]

**Edit**
 4. You have to use bodyParser.raw() if your passing raw json

```
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ inflate: true, limit: '100kb', type: 'text/xml' }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route is written as a post request. So, when you try to search for it through the browser that request will be treated as a get request. if you want to test your post requests try it with some tools like Postman.